# Communication between iOS app in one Wi-Fi network w/o server

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, wifi

I need to communicate my app with 2 devices. A restriction is that I can't use a server but all iOS devices will be in one Wi-Fi network. What options do I have? How I can send a message to another copy of my app running on another device?

Comment: Did you try advertizing your app's listening port with [Bonjour](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/PublishingServices.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know whether its a correct approach or not but as you cannot use server,so the approach i can think of is we can create a socket connection using TCP/IP or UDP(based on reliability) for data exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can communicate between 2 devices running the same application without having some kind of server application in-between.

Even if you could find the other device over the WIFI I dont think you can tell if the other device is running the app or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be referring to MultipeerConnectivity

> The Multipeer Connectivity framework provides support for discovering
>   services provided by nearby iOS devices using infrastructure Wi-Fi
>   networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth personal area networks and
>   subsequently communicating with those services by sending
>   message-based data, streaming data, and resources (such as files).

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/

Apple Sample:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html